# Two way databinding with custom converter

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I want to use databinding with a viewmodel as explained [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way#converters)

So here are excerpts:

layout:

```
    <data class="FragmentEditPersonDataBinding">
    <import type="com.unludo.interview.persons.edit.Converter"/>

    <variable
        name="viewmodel"
        type="com.unludo.interview.persons.edit.PersonEditViewModel" />
   [...]
                 <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editBirthday"
                android:inputType="date"
                android:text="@={Converter.dateToString(viewmodel.birthday)}"
```

converter:

```
object Converter {
    @InverseMethod("stringToDate")
    @JvmStatic
    fun dateToString(
            view: EditText, oldValue: String,
            value: Date
    ): String {
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.FRANCE)

        return sdf.format(value)
    }

    @JvmStatic   
    fun stringToDate(
            view: EditText, oldValue: String,
            value: String
    ): Date {
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.FRANCE)

        return sdf.parse(value)
    }
}
```

viewmodel:

```
class PersonEditViewModel {
    var birthday: Date = GregorianCalendar(1993, 5, 19).time
    ...
```

Now I get this error when I build:

```
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: 
    Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:cannot find method dateToString(java.util.Date) 
    in class com.unludo.interview.persons.edit.Converter 
[...]
 - 134:78 ****\ data binding error ****
```

I am using the latest databinding alpha, so I am wondering if there could be a bug inthe lib.

thx for any help!

--- update

If I write the converter like this then it compiles, but that does not correspond to the documentation. Any idea why?

```
object Converter {

    @InverseMethod("stringToDate")
    @JvmStatic
    fun dateToString(
            value: Date
    ): String {
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.FRANCE)

        return sdf.format(value)
    }
    @JvmStatic
    fun stringToDate(
            value: String
    ): Date {
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.FRANCE)

        return sdf.parse(value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try **@JvmStatic** annotation on your *dateToString* converter method? May be databinding compiler fails to find static method `dateToString`.

Comment: @JeelVankhede I just tried but no change

Comment: If you're having this **object class** in this package *com.unludo.interview.persons.edit* then try this annotation at start of your object file `@file:JvmName("Converter")`.

Comment: @JeelVankhede Still the same

Comment: @JeelVankhede I tried that too but still the same. I found a way but it's not supposed to work like that.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of an old thread, but I've also been struggling with 2-way databinding, so for anyone that needs the answer to this, the issue is that Unlundo made their converter the way is documented, where there's a View, and old, and a new value. The documentation for this is not very clear, however.

The arguments in you type converters must also be present in your layout file. For the original binding in the layout, `android:text="@={Converter.dateToString(viewmodel.birthday)}"`, there is only one argument - `viewmodel.birthday`, which we assume is a date. Therefore, our type converter and inverse converter only get 1 argument.

If you reuse the same converter for multiple bindings and want to be able to see what view the user changed, you can pass the view as an argument by using it's ID in the layout. This will pass in the birthday, and the view that the user was editing:

```xml
                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editBirthday"
                android:inputType="date"
                android:text="@={Converter.dateToString(edtBirthday, viewmodel.birthday)}"
```

This will also mean your type converter and inverse converter both need an additional argument in the beginning for the EditText. The library does seem to be smart enough to get the type of view correct, and not just give you a `View` as your argument, at least.

Also, if you're struggling with the converter only firing in the direction to string, make sure you actually set the binding variable. If the variable the layout is binding from is `null`, it will convert default values to display, but it won't be able to bind anything back